How to handle prompt dialog on Playwright with 2 inputs
Im trying to handle prompt dialog on Playwright with 2 inputs but it's not working.
Actually, Im using a list of string on dialog.accept() function, but nothing happens
this is the code script im using :
page.on('dialog',async dialog => {
      expect(dialog.type()).toContain('prompt');
      await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
      await dialog.accept('{"username","pass"}');
      await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
    });
    await page.goto("url",{ timeout: 60000 });

the goto page who trigger the prompt dialog
Any idea how to fix this please ?
Thanks,

What do you mean with 2 inputs?

The documented use is await dialog.accept(promptText) - with a the single string parameter - his dialog has 2 inputs and want to know how to fill them both (username and password).

If the dialog has two inputs, I'd suggest it's not an alert(), confirm(), or prompt() dialog. The code can't be fixed, throw it away and write normal form testing code.

But the 2 inputs I had cannot inspect them because they are on prompt dialog, so even I tried normal code
await this.page.getByTitle('Username').fill('xxxx');
await this.page.waitForTimeout(3000);
await this.page.getByTitle('Password').fill('xxxxx');
await this.page.locator("button:has-text('Sign in')").click();
It does not work
@ Peter Lorre
